# jQuery Ajax Upload problem with dynamically inserted divs

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to use Ajax Upload (http://valums.com/ajax-upload/), a jQuery plugin for async. file uploads.

To use the plugin, you're supposed to create an qq.FileUploader object, pass an options object and attach the object to a 'div' in the DOM.

My problem is that the plugin works as long as the 'div' wasn't dynamically inserted (via .append() etc). When I use a dynamically inserted div, the upload button (see website) that's supposed to be put into the div by the plugin doesn't show at all. It seems the plugin can't find the div.

Does anyone have experience using the plugin, especially using it with dynamically inserted DOM elements?

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue on another similar function.  This plugin solved it.  http://plugins.jquery.com/project/livequery

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [Mike Alsup's](http://malsup.com/jquery/) [form plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form)? It does background file uploads incredibly well using the native  element.